# Hibernate query: could not resolve property

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, hql

I'm getting the following error when trying to run this Hibernate query:

```
could not resolve property: candidateID of: result [select SUM(A.Points) from answer A Left Join A.Results R where R.candidateID = '465b4eb2-c306-4092-8914-d272b5a70b11']
QueryString     select SUM(A.Points) from answer A Left Join A.Results R where R.candidateID = '465b4eb2-c306-4092-8914-d272b5a70b11'
```

**code**

```
select SUM(A.Points)
 from answer A
 Left Join A.Results R 
 where R.candidateID = '1234'
```

However,candidateID is in results so i don't understand this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the exception of names of Java classes and properties, HQL queries are case-insensitive.  So org.hibernate.eg.FOO is not org.hibernate.eg.Foo.  Try changing the case on your query for classes and properties.  Also verify the case for candidateID.

```
select SUM(A.points) from Answer A Left Join A.results R where R.candidateID = '465b4eb2-c306-4092-8914-d272b5a70b11']
```

Answer (score 1):

Entity `Results` do not have field named `candidateID`. In HQL queries names of the persistent attributes (~ fields in class) should be used instead of names of database columns.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about hibernate, but if that were normal sql this line is incomplete:

```
Left Join A.Results R
```

You have to specify a joining condition such as

```
Left Join A.Results R on a.candidateID = R.candidateID
```

Comment: This does not seem to be true [in the case of HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins).